# I'm getting an error: Register-SPWorkflowService : The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I installed SP Server 2013 and Workflow Manager in one server. When I configure Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint Server 2013 farm (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588), I am encountering this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sp2013/sit
es/assetmgt" -WorkflowHostUri "https://localhost:12290"

Register-SPWorkflowService : The root of the certificate chain is not a
trusted root authority.
```

My command seems to be fine, as opposed to what I have researched so far (problems that other users had). Does anyone know the solution here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a post I did yesterday on

> Configuring SharePoint Workflow Service Manager in SP 2013

. Please go through this post and see if you have missed any steps.

[Read Full Post](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Configuring-SharePoint-2013-to-support-workflow-Management-Service.aspx)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92562/discussion-on-answer-by-biju-joseph-mcsd-im-getting-an-error-register-spwork).